# How to remove added files while adding files next time in fileupload js?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

While uploading multiple files using fileupload js, the files that are added in first time are not removing while adding files next time, how to remove that files.

For example, first I am adding four files and then adding different four files instead of first four, while uploading, it uploads all the eight files. How to upload only the last added four files only.

```
function saveSOPFiles(){
var filesList = [];
$('#sopFiles').fileupload({
url : "UploadSOPFiles",
autoUpload: false,
replaceFileInput : false,
formData:{extra:1},
fileInput: $("#sopFiles")
}).on("fileuploadadd", function (e, data) {
filesList.push(data.files[0]);
});

$("#uploadSOPFiles").click(function () {
$('#sopFiles').fileupload('send', {
files: filesList
});
}
});
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/refas39r/

Comment: Check the contents of data.files[0] on the second upload (using console.log).  Does it only contain the newly added files?

Comment: yes, i checked, it does not contain second uploaded files....

Comment: and you checked the contents of filesList before you push the new files?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect $("#sopFiles") might contain all of the files (new and old).  If that's the case, you need to remove the old files from $("#sopFiles") after saving to the server (and validating the files are saved server side).

```
$("#uploadSOPFiles").click(function () {
  $('#sopFiles').fileupload('send', {
    files: filesList
  });
}
$("#sopFiles").val('')  //not sure what type of input $("#sopFiles") is so you may need to adjust this.
```